# GCC does not complain about re-definition of external variable?

Tags: c, gcc, redefinition

This simple code (MCVE):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 3;
int main(){
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
int a; // This line
```

To my surprise, GCC (MinGW GCC 4.8.2, 4.9.2 and 6.3.0) does not give any error, not even warnings about the marked line! However it does if I assign a value to `a` at its second definition.

More strangely, `g++` tells me that the second re-definition is an error, but `gcc` doesn't.

Isn't it supposed to be a re-definition of an existing variable because there's no keyword `extern`?

Comment: uninitialized globals are implicitly `extern`.

Comment: It would complain if both had initializers.  It is required not to complain when written thus.  The second is a tentative definition. You more normally see the uninitialized declaration first, but it is OK as written.

Comment: if uninitialized globals are implicitly `extern`  that would mean that `int a; ... int a;` would be equivalent to `extern int a; ... extern int a;`, but latter doesn't link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the C Standard (6.9.2 External object definitions)

> 1 If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and
>   an initializer, the declaration is **an external definition for the
>   identifier**.

and

> 2 A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope
>   without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with
>   the storage-class specifier static, **constitutes a tentative
>   definition**. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative
>   definitions for an identifier, and the translation unit contains no
>   external definition for that identifier, then the behavior is exactly
>   as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that
>   identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation
>   unit, with an initializer equal to 0.

And there is an example in the C Standard

```
int i1 = 1; // definition, external linkage
//...
int i1; // valid tentative definition, refers to previous
```

So in your program this one declaration

```
int a = 3;
```

is an external definition for the identifier `a`

and this one

```
int a;
```

is a tentative definition that refers to the previous external definition of the identifier.

If to use an initializer in the second declaration then you will get two external definitions for the identifier and the compiler will issue an error because only one external definition can exist.

Take into account that C and C++ differ relative to this context,

From the C++ Standard (C.1.2 Clause 6: basic concepts)

6.1

> Change: C++ does not have “tentative definitions” as in C. E.g., at
>   file scope,

```
int i;
int i;
```

> is valid in C, invalid in C++.

Comment: So the second `int a;` can be written as `static int a;` with the same effect (implicit `extern`)?

Comment: @iBug It may not be written with the static keyword because it already has external definition. The same identifier may not have external and internal linkage in the same translation unit.

Comment: Notable, C11 future language directions: "Declaring an identifier with internal linkage at file scope without the static storage class specifier is an obsolescent feature."

Answer (score 2):

It is called **tentative definitions** in C.

[Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/extern) say's :

> **Tentative definitions**
>
> A tentative definition is an external declaration without an
>   initializer, and either without a storage-class specifier or with the
>   specifier static.
>
> A tentative definition is a declaration that may or may not act as a
>   definition. If an actual external definition is found earlier or later
>   in the same translation unit, then the tentative definition just acts
>   as a declaration.
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> int i3; // tentative definition, external linkage
>
> int i3; // tentative definition, external linkage 
>
> extern int i3; // declaration, external linkage
> ```